# Using the awk command with array to transform row to column

Tags: awk

Good Morning ,

Help in generating a file containing several lines will be a column.

file movimenta.txt

```
data             medicine         value
====             =======         =====
01.01.2019 01:00   m1             1
01.01.2019 02:00   m1             2
01.01.2019 03:00   m1             5
01.01.2019 04:00   m1             6
01.01.2019 01:00   m2             12
01.01.2019 02:00   m2             22
01.01.2019 03:00   m2             52
01.01.2019 04:00   m2             62
01.01.2019 01:00   m3             13
01.01.2019 02:00   m3             23
01.01.2019 03:00   m3             53
01.01.2019 03:00   m3             63
```

file data.txt    (grouped)

```
data
====
01.01.2019 01:00   
01.01.2019 02:00   
01.01.2019 03:00   
01.01.2019 04:00
```

file medicine.txt   (grouped)

```
remedio
=======
m1
m2
m3
```

** difficulty in assembling the file below ****
columnar.txt file (it would be the junction of the three files where the data.txt file would have plus the line in the movimenta.txt file would be a column in this file)

```
data                   m1      m2    m3
01.01.2019 01:00       1       12    13
01.01.2019 02:00       2       22    23
01.01.2019 03:00       5       52    53
01.01.2019 04:00       6       62    63
```

Note: The movimenta.txt file is dynamic where you can have more medicine in your next generation and you can have the medicine m4, m5, m6, m7, etc etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: what is the difference between the 3rd and 4th data values (time stamps)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the `data` and `medicine` files?  Or is it enough to show just the date/time stamps and medicines listed in the `movimenta` file?  Here's a script that gets you the desired output format based just one on the one file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS = "   *m?";}

NR > 2 {
    listOfDt[$1] = 1;
    sumData[$1,$2] = $3;
    if (max < $2) {max = $2;}
}

END {
    printf("%-16s","data");
    for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {printf("%6s","m" i);}
    print "";

    for (dt in listOfDt) {
        line = sprintf("%-16s",dt);
        for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            line = line sprintf("%6d",sumData[dt,i]);
        }
        print line | "sort";
    }
}
```

If the name of the above file is `medicine-summary`, you'd use it like this:

```sh
medicine-summary movimenta.txt
```

Based on the data above, it outputs

```
data                m1    m2    m3
01.01.2019 01:00     1    12    13
01.01.2019 02:00     2    22    23
01.01.2019 03:00     5    52    63
01.01.2019 04:00     6    62     0
```

(you didn't include an entry for m3 at 04:00 in the sample movimenta file).

Note the use of "at least 2 spaces plus 0 or 1 letter m" as the field separator.

For lines 2+ of the file, it keeps a list of the distinct date/time values, as well as the value for each medicine at that date/time value, and the largest medicine identifier.

In the END block it prints each date/time stamp represented in the file, along with values for each medicine represented in the file, piping the output to the UNIX `sort` command so the data are presented in chronological order (but only if all the data are for the same month--better to format the dates as `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM` for easier sorting and to avoid confusion as to whether the existing format is `dd.mm.yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy`).

What this *won't* show is

- any date/time value from the `data` file that isn't represented in the `movimenta` file
- medicine identifiers from the `medicine` file that are greater than the largest one making an appearance in the `moviementa` file